# ERROR: "dependent name is not a type". When use typedef type in class as return value, with template

Tags: c++

```
template <class Item>
class bag
{
public:
    //TYPEDEF
    typedef size_t size_type;
    typedef Item value_type;
...
}
```

and when I use

```
template<class Item>
bag<Item>::size_type bag<Item>::count(const Item& target) const
```

VC++ report error as 
Source.cpp(207): warning C4346: 'bag::size_type' : dependent name is not a type

Could anybody show me why? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It should be

```
template<class Item>
typename bag<Item>::size_type bag<Item>::count(const Item& target) const
```

Answer (score 49):

You need to prepend `typename` before `bag<Item>::size_type` as it is a *dependent type*.

```
typename bag<Item>::size_type bag<Item>::count(const Item& target) const
```

As per the C++11 Standard:

> **14.6 Name resolution**
>
> A name used in a template declaration or deﬁnition and that is dependent on a template-parameter is assumed not to name a type unless the applicable name lookup ﬁnds a type name or the name is qualiﬁed by the keyword `typename`.

Related: [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Comment: Thank you! I followed your suggestion and have fixed my problem.

Comment: Ah, typename is needed for the size_type, thank you. This is still required in C++17. Is it still required in C++20 I wonder?