# Templated type alias with nested struct

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, type-alias

I have a simple header file that stands for a templated BST implementation, and would like to create a type alias to a nested struct but to no avail...

**Header**

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>

using namespace std;

namespace NYNE {

    template <typename T>
    class BST {

    protected:

        struct Node {
            T data;
            shared_ptr<Node> previous;
            shared_ptr<Node> next;

            Node(const T& t);
            Node(const T& t, const shared_ptr<T>& previous, const shared_ptr<T>& next);

            Node& smaller() const;
            Node& bigger() const;
        };

        int m_num_elements;

        shared_ptr<Node> m_first;

    public:

        BST();

        bool insert(const T& element);
        bool remove(const T& element);
    };
}
```

**Implementation**

```
#include "BST.h"

using namespace NYNE;

template <typename T>
BST<T>::BST() {
    m_num_elements = 0;
    m_first = nullptr;
}

template <typename T>
using typename Node = BST<T>::Node;       // <- here

template <typename T>
BST<T>::Node::Node(const T& t) {
    data = t;
    smaller() = nullptr;
    bigger() = nullptr;
}

template <typename T>
BST<T>::Node::Node(const T& t, const shared_ptr<T>& previous, const shared_ptr<T>& next) {
    data = t;
    smaller() = previous;
    bigger() = next;
}
```

I don't understand if the problem is with the header file or the type alias declaration itself.

Compiler error below (it literally means nothing).

> bst.cpp(12): error C2059: erreur de syntaxe : ''

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is splitting templates into cpp/h files supported now?

Comment: Can you please show the compiler error?

Comment: I added the compiler error.

Comment: `typename` in the wrong place? `template <typename T> using Node = typename BST<T>::Node; `

Comment: What @Barry said, as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/16131862/7034621

Comment: I think I understand the problem now: the template wasn't instanciated anywhere so my `.h` file results of 0 lines of compiled code, therefore `BST<T>::Node` is not a type when compiling the `.cpp` file. I had already tried the `typename` thing. Thanks anyway.

Comment: [Your code compiles](http://rextester.com/KYFV30312) once "the `typename` thing" is fixed. What other problem do you understand to be having?

Comment: @NikitaKniazev Nope!